# No WiFi in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu

I recently installed Xubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba Satellite.  To my dismay, I could not get a WiFi connection.  I know the computer has WiFi, because it worked before.  I can get a wired connection.  I've even tried putting in a WiFi adapter and letting it connect over night.  It still didn't work.  It just keeps asking for my WiFi password.  Why is this?

Comment: See if http://docs.xubuntu.org/1204/internet-networks.html#network-troubleshooting-wireless is of help to you.

Comment: i have had the same problem before. if there are no drivers for your wifi card, get `ndiswrapper` and use windows drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebooted your Toshiba any time recently?  I had a similar issue with my ASUS netbook and realized that it only happened after it had been on for a long time.  My settings were to lockscreen when the laptop lid is closed so it ran for long periods of time.  I changed my power settings to suspend when the lid is closed and rebooted and this resolved my issue.